# Necessity of Messaging in a Java EE Solution

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, java-ee-6, messaging

Consider a worker process which searches the web for particular data. Another process is needed to index the results of the first process for later use. The indexing part involves writing raw data (search results) to a huge distributed HBase repository in a particular way. I can't judge about the speed of these two processes compared to each other. We may have a situation in which one of these systems is temporarily down and needs to take the task where it is put upon its wake-up. I'm using JavaEE. Currently, this is the way I have in mind to implement this.

1. The first process stores the result of its search in a MySQL database and sends a message containing the IDs of the new rows it has put in the table.
2. The MOM wakes up the second process to consume the new raw data stored in the MySQL database.
3. The second process clears up the MySQL table when it finishes indexing the data in the real database (HBase).

I need expert comments on my design to verify its appropriateness. For instance, what if the second process continuously polls the table to see if there is new records? Am I using the correct technology or it is an overkill? Should I simplify my design or am I missing something? If my solution is appropriate, is there something I should keep in mind during the implementation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick to a simpler design if possible, ditch the MySQL staging table and stick to JMS.

So, something like this would do it:

1. [P1] sends the search result to some JMS queue "INDEX.QUEUE".
2. [P2] Simply eats messages of the queue "INDEX.QUEUE" asyncrhonously and generates search indices from the search result in the message payload.

Messaging is there to help you with these tasks, polling a database table is pretty much the same, but trickier, so why reinvent the wheel when you have a persistent and transactional MOM available that is designed for this task.

Comment: Thanks. What would happen if the messages grow in size? Consider tens of messages in the queue, each having a size of 10-50 MB. Is it better to have that staging table in a situation like this, or it simply doesn't make a difference?

Comment: Sure. Size does matter, but <50MB should be just fine for all major vendors. 

Actually, the technology under the hood of JMS implementations and databases does not differ that much, in some implementations, JMS messages are even stored inside database tables. 

You have not stated which software stack you run on, but you might have to tweak the limits in the configuration of the MOM. Often the max total size of messages in a queue just a matter of physical server resources. I've seen GBs of data on single queues waiting for processing without issues.

Comment: I'm using GlassFish v3 which can be easily configured to use a database for message storage, as you just stated. Your advice really helped.

Comment: Good! That said, I'm not really sure that using a database as message store is the best solution in all cases, performance wise. But that depends on what you think is most important. I don't know performance details about Glassfish/OpenMQ anyway.